# Debian Jessie server would not reboot after update, have access by Rescue, but not sure what to do

Tags: debian, web-server, rescue-disk

Not getting any help from my host from my tickets. Server down fo 24 hours now as I try to google solutions.
Upgraded server to Jessie as an upgrade to Wheezy produced errors, and before reboot everything was up and running, but as all upgrade docs and info I read, I rebooted server. However never came back. 
I have the original backup files before I did the Wheezy upgrade.
I also have access by Rescue to the server, however the docs supplied are not helpful.
Made a back up of critical files and have a 24GB tar file, but the Rescue FTP won't connect to the host FTP back up (says the username/password wrong which is given by the host and can't connect by FTP remotely with those details either). I can connect by SFTP and pull down smaller tar and zip files.

I am confused about how to check the Debian files... Grub etc.

I am not able to sudo from Putty. I cannot run apt-get update. I did go to chroot, but then I get unable to resolve host errors and Could not open lock file because Permission denied errors and asking if I am root.

Any suggestions what to do next?

Sure I can pull all the sites down over sftp and reinitialize the server and start again but that is hours of uploading. (I have the sites backed up locally)

Comment: This is a sprawling question without much useable information.  When you try to reboot, what exactly happens? What do the console and boot logs (/var/log/boot.log, /var/log/syslog, /var/log/kern.log) tell you? If the thing won't boot and you can't tell why, then your best choice is probably going to be to start over.

Comment: @Andrew Schulman Sorry for the sprawl, but your reply is helpful as I did not know where to start to check. The server is remote and I have no console. boot log is empty and the kern log has no entry for the actual reboot time, and the syslog entry appears to be last entry as server went down for reboot. Your advice to restart is probably the right answer.